# Problem while writing a data at the end of the file using the system calls in c

Tags: c, system-calls, file-handling

I am trying to write data at the end of the file so I am first moving the file pointer at the end of the file using the lseek() system call in c and then I am writing that data at end of the file using write() but I have two issue the first is when i am accepting data from the user to write into the file it only takes up to first whitespace and second after writing the data it writes garbage values in the file after writing the user accepted data.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<io.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main()
{
   char Fname[30];
   char Data[1024];
   int fd = 0;
   int iSize = 0;
   int iRet = 0;

   printf("Enter The File Name: -");
   scanf("%[^'\n']s",Fname);

   fd = open(Fname,O_RDWR);

   if(fd == -1)
   {
     printf("Unable To Open File");
     return -1;
   }
   else
   {
     printf("File Open Successfully\n");
   }

   printf("Enter The String To Write At End Of The File: -");
   scanf("%s",Data);

   iRet = lseek(fd,0L,SEEK_END);

   if(iRet == -1)
   {
     printf("Unable To Perform Operation On File");
     return -1;
   }

   fd = write(fd,Data,sizeof(Data));

   if(fd == -1)
   {
     printf("Unable To Write Data Into File");
     return -1;
   } 
   else
   {
     printf("Data Written Into The File Successfully\n");
   }

   close(fd);

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: "*it only takes up to first whitespace*". That's exactly what `%s` means. Read the [scanf manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Use something like `fgets` instead if you want to read a whole line.

Comment: *"writes garbage*". That's because `sizeof(Data)` is the entire buffer including the part of the buffer that was not set by the `scanf`. Use `strlen(Data)` instead.

Comment: @kaylum thanks a lot it works. but I try to use same regex that I have applied in above but it terminates program what is reason behind this ?

Comment: I wish programming courses stopped using `scanf` and started using `argv` a lot more. The `scanf` function is not easy for beginners to learn to use well.

Comment: @Manish Tambe - There is no _regex_ in your program.